# Find the largest $c$.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose $p,q$ are variables such that $0 < p,q < 1$, and

$$ p\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)+(1-p)\ln\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)-4c(p-q)^2\ge 0$$

Determine the largest $c$ such that the inequality holds for all $0 < p,q < 1$.

Comment: $\ln\left(\frac{1-(1)}{1-(1)}\right)=\ln\frac00$ You need to fix your bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\ln$ is strictly increasing so $x\gt y\Rightarrow \ln x\gt\ln y$.

We have the given expression is equivalent to
 $$\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{1-p}\ge\ln e^{4c(p-q)^2}$$ hence, because the logarithm is injective,

$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{1-p}\ge e^{4c(p-q)^2}$$ 
The maximum of $c$ is reached when we have the equality, i.e.

$$\color{red}{c=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{1-p}}{4(p-q)^2}}$$

Should consider the case where $q\to p $ . In this case one has
$$\color{red}{c}=\lim_{q\to p}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)^{1-p}}{4(p-q)^2}\color{red}{=\frac{1}{8p(1-p)}}$$

Comment: $p$ is also a variable. So I think the solution is not complete yet. And why should we consider the case $q\rightarrow p$

Comment: When you have $p=q$ (which is not forbidden in this question) the given answer take the form $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Note that $p(1-p)\le \frac14$, so $c\ge \frac12$ and hence the max of $c$ is $\frac12$.

Comment: @xpaul: You are right. It was the final part of $c=\frac{1}{8p(1-p)}$ because $p$ is variable. I have taken the value of $c$ for given values of $p$ and $q$. The rest follows.